# while nesting a dictionary inside a list, getting a TypeError : string indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, indices

```
friend_0 = {
    'first_name' : 'wong', 
    'last_name' : 'cap bawong', 
    'age' : 16, 
    }

friend_1 = {
    'first_name' : 'lele',
    'last_name' : 'cap meong',
    'age' : 46,
    }

friend_2 = {
    'first_name' : 'kucing',
    'last_name' : 'nan indah',
    'age' : 18
    }

people = [friend_0, friend_1, friend_2]

for person in people:
    for k in person.keys():
        **friend = f"{k['first_name'].title()} {k['last_name'].title()}"**
        print (f"\nName: {friend}")
        print (f"\tAge: {k['age']}")
```

i got error in the line of: friend = f"{k['first_name'].title()}
{k['last_name'].title()}"

> FileType error - string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for person in people:
    friend = f"{person['first_name'].title()} {person['last_name'].title()}"
    print(f"\nName: {friend}")
    print(f"\tAge: {person['age']}")
```

Comment: you dont have to loop again on each person becouse if you extrect with the key explictly. at each loop we have a single person, and we can extrect the data with the keys like `'first_name'.
(please kindly mark my answer if i solved your problem)